# disable native player for embedded youtube video in ios using phonegap

Tags: ios, youtube, cordova

I embed a youtube video into html like this;

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mYVckxZVI_g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
    </div>
</body>
```

But when I clicked play button of embedded video, a player of iphone is opened.
How can I disable this player. Because I want to control player using javascript.

Can you help?

[image: Screenshot]

.

Comment: I mean if you want to control the video using javascript, it's entirely possible.  Have you tried looking into the [Youtube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).  Additionally, If that's not the way you want to go, the only thing I can think of (and I may be wrong), is that you would have to create your own custom video player.  A quick Google search pointed me to [Make a Custom Youtube Player](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/).

Comment: I have already a player. But When I moved my player into phonegap(ios), default player of iphone is opened. But when i tried on ipad, everything is ok.